# Algorithm for matching songs

Tags: algorithm, audio, pattern-matching

Say I have 20 songs in my iPhone's music collection

A song comes up on the television which might or might not be an exact duplicate of a song I have in my collection.

( not a cover,  the exact same song -- this should make it a little easier )

I record 20 seconds out of this song using my iPhone.

I need an algorithm to detect whether this song matches some song in my collection.

This is my first port of call.  As research yields results, I will add an answer to my own question, or edit the question.

So this is my question: how to accomplish this task?  Is there any commercially or freely available software?  Are there any documented known methods?

I'm imagining the first step will be to process source and target sound waves into a series of vectors ( maybe cepstral coefficients? ) and then perform some sort of pattern matching.

maybe I can hijack some well-known matching algorithm?

Comment: Check out [this article about the algorithm used by Shazam](http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/), a service which identifies songs based on short samples.

Comment: Do you want to download some working library, or do you want to make one on your own? If so, have a look at [how Shazam works (pdf document)](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf). It's more detailed version of the article linked above.

Comment: @TomsonTom, I don't want to reinvent the wheel :) if I can find a commercially available engine that I can get a licence for that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

http://echoprint.me/

this is open source and already contains a library for use with iOS

it looks like it is ready to run